# Printing Panel Content

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to print panel content. Content contains some text and images.
 Text is printed properly, but images are not printed.
I am using below code :

```
PrintHelper.PrintWebControl(Panel1);
```

In print preview images are not shown, and also not printed as well, rest is working fine.

Comment: Is this server-side code?  Are you printing server-side or client-side?  What does this `PrintHelper` actually do?  Is the print preview rendering in a browser somewhere?  Can you inspect the DOM in that browser window at all?  How is it rendering the preview, perhaps by using the `print` CSS media type?  Can you monitor network calls (either in-browser with a debugging tool or outside the browser with something like Fiddler) to see if it's trying to request the images and failing?  It's jut really not clear what's going on here.

Comment: For as long as I can remember, my browser (IE) allows me to set my print settings to not allow printing images or backgrounds. (hint).

Comment: @David The printhelper class makes a call to window.print(). It is one of classes provided by asp.net for printing web controls.

Comment: @nocturns2 Offcourse my image print settings in my browser are turned on.

Comment: Someone answer this question please